# Magento 2 - Session based authentication doesn't work

Tags: magento2, session, permissions, webapi

I don't know if this is a bug in Magento 2 API or not, so I didn't post it on Magento 2 Github issues.

According to this link: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-session.html:

> Customers can access resources that are configured with anonymous or
>   self permission in the webapi.xml configuration file.

I tried login Magento 2 storefront, then I went to `magento_host/rest/V1/customers/me` on the browser (which has "self" permission), I still got error

> Consumer is not authorized to access %resources

I tried to create a custom API which also has "self" permission, I got the same error.

I'm using Magento 2.1.7.

Anyone know why?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The session based authentication (with "self" permission) is only allowed to AJAX calls and not to browser requests due to security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please share the example of it?

Answer (score 0):

Setting an additional header in your `fetch` does actually solve the issue, so

```
fetch('/rest/V1/customers/me', {headers: {"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}}).then(res => res.json()) //...
```

does actually succeed - like

```
jquery.ajax('/rest/V1/customers/me' // ...
```

would. To be sure about caches, my solution in the end was:

```
fetch('/rest/V1/customers/me?_='+(new Date().getTime()), {headers: {"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}}) // ...
```

The actual additional security is pretty much zero - but that's the way to go in M2